# Convert Boolean Value to String

Tags: powershell

I am trying to convert my boolean values in PowerShell to the following:

- True → GREEN
- False → RED

Here is my relevant code for this

```
$SecMasSQLRes | ForEach-Object {
    if ($SecMasSQLRes.CusipPercent -lt 25) {
        Write-Host CusipStatus = GREEN
    } else {
        Write-Host CusipStatus = RED
    }

    if ($SecMasSQLRes.ISINPercent -lt 10) {
        Write-Host IsinStatus = GREEN
    } else {
        Write-Host IsinStatus = RED
    }

    if ($SecMasSQLRes.SymbolPercent -lt 10) {
        Write-Host SymbolStatus = GREEN
    } else {
        Write-Host SymbolStatus = RED
    }
}

$CusipResults = $SecMasSQLRes.CusipPercent -lt 25
$IsinResults = $SecMasSQLRes.ISINPercent -lt 10
$SymbolResults = $SecMasSQLRes.SymbolPercent -lt 10

$CusipResults
$IsinResults
$SymbolResults
```

Comment: `$variable = if(condition) {'GREEN'} else {'RED'}`

Comment: `$lookup = @{$false='RED';$true='GREEN'}; $lookup[$MyBool]`

Comment: Golf'd: `@('RED','GREEN')[$bool]`

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways how you could approach this:

- Use an `if`/`else` statement as suggested by [@PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584332/powershell-convert-boolean-value-to-string#comment60767818_36584332):

  ```
  if (condition) {'GREEN'} else {'RED'}
  ```
- Use a `switch` statement:

  ```
  switch (condition) { $true {'GREEN'} default {'RED'} }
  ```
- Use a hashtable as suggested by [@TessellatingHeckler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584332/powershell-convert-boolean-value-to-string#comment60768782_36584332):

  ```
  $light = @{$true = 'GREEN'; $false = 'RED'}
  $light[(condition)]
  ```
- Use the boolean values (implicitly cast to integers) as index in an array as suggested by [@Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584332/powershell-convert-boolean-value-to-string#comment60781805_36584332):

  ```
  @('RED', 'GREEN')[(condition)]
  ```

Personally, I think the hashtable method is the cleanest approach, so I'd prefer that one:

```
$light = @{
    $true  = 'GREEN'
    $false = 'RED'
}

$SecMasSQLRes | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host CusipStatus = $light[($_.CusipPercent -lt 25)]
    Write-Host IsinStatus = $light[($_.ISINPercent -lt 10)]
    Write-Host SymbolStatus = $light[($_.SymbolPercent -lt 10)]
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, went a different route, but I will definitely try these suggestions.